# Git: Read all Commit Messages from Remote Repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I need a git command that let's me read all the commit messages from my remote repository.

I work on a local PC, push my code onto the repository from there, and then pull it onto my server.

I tried `git log`, which shows all the commit messages on my local PC, but when used on the server it only shows me "Initial commit".

Is there a way to view all of them on the server?

Comment: have you pushed the changes to the remote.?

Comment: @ZahidKhan Yes. When I look at my Gitlab repository online in my browser I can see all the commits there with the messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do:

```
git fetch --all
git log origin/<branch-name>
```

Comment: yup, i did :D just had to wait for the 30 seconds to pass to be able to

Comment: Note that `--all` on `git fetch` means *all remotes*. It is similar to running `git remote update`, except that `git remote update` is much fancier, handling remote *groups* if defined. It's rare-ish to have more than one remote and to want to update all of them with`git fetch`, but it's not so rare as to be unheard-of: sometimes you have two remotes and having `git fetch` update both is nice.